# PowerBuilder Unit Tests exiting with error code -1073741819 in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: unit-testing, cruisecontrol.net, nant, powerbuilder

I have some unit tests set up in my PowerBuilder application that run through CruiseControl.NET via a NAnt script.

In the past few days I've come across an issue where every test run will return the error code `-1073741819`, which I can't seem to find much information about.

I have come across this error in the past when the .exe was set to run a whole bunch of tests at once, but I managed to work around this by having only a single test at a time, with the test number passed as a command line paramater to my unit test exe. I then have a for loop in my NAnt script that will loop through each test to run it. For well over 6 months this seemed to be a viable solution (I was thinking that maybe it was an out of memory error, since it seemed to happen only when more than 50 test were run in a single instance.)

Has anyone had any experience with unit tests in PowerBuilder? I believe the unit test framework used is *PBUnit*, though I'm not entirely sure (if this is important I can find out.) It's setup so that it compiles the program to an exe (lets say main.exe,) and to run the unit tests you just need to pass particular command line paramaters to main.exe when launching, and it will start running the unit tests rather than launching the program.

If there's any particular piece if information that anyone needs to help me find a solution, let me know and I'll see what I can find out.

Thanks,
Josh.

---

**Edit 1 (13/12/2011 1:39PM)**

Attached is a screenshot of the event viewer error that shows up when running it from the command line via remote desktop.

[image: Event Viewer Error]

---

**Edit 2 (13/12/2011 2:08PM)**

Attached is a screenshot of the event viewer error that shows up when running it from CruiseControl.NET

[image: Event Viewer Error via CruiseControl]

Comment: Is there anything in the Windows event log when these failures occur?

Comment: Hi Dave, yes, there is an error. I've attached a screenshot of the event viewer error to the original quesiton (under edit1.) I'm presuming that the fault address (which is dec 19731063) is just random. I'll run it a couple of times and post if the address changes. Edit: I've run it a couple of times with different tests and the fault address appears to be the same. Possibly a hardware issue? The only problem I can think with that is that it's a virtual machine.

Comment: I saw a couple of posts in various places that equate that error code with Windows error c00000005, which is an access exception. Given PB's idiosyncrasies, how long has the VM been running? I *hate* the "try a reboot" answer, but sometimes it's the only thing for PB.

Comment: I managed to reboot it yesterday (I'm not sure how long since it's last reboot,) and it's still having the issue. I have though found out that the license server may have been moved to a different subnet (I didn't realise this had taken place,) and that has coincided with this issue. The issue has come on before, but only when multiple tests are run at once (which now they're not, they run once at a time.) Now they are all failing no matter what, so I'll wait until the server is back on the same subnet as the license server and see if that sorts it out. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this instance was the servers were moved and the firewall was blocking access to the database server.

I have had this problem in the past though (but in this instance it was happening with every test, that has never happened before,) and the easiest solution is to setup a script that runs one test at a time. I'm pretty sure it's a memory error, so maybe it run's out of memory. Just thought I'd post this if anyone else if having issues with it.

It's one of those quirks in PowerBuilder that I can't just figure out a real solution, only a workaround.